# Топ-меню на сайте: выделение и нажатие при наведении

Tags: html, css

Не могу создать топ-меню, а именно анимацию двух кнопок в топ-меню. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Создал текстовой документ, в нем написал это

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; windows-1251" http-equiv="Content-Type">
            <meta content="Лучшие инфопродукты для домашнего бизнеса" name="description"/>
            <meta content="магазин продуктов, видео уроки, видеоуроки, видеокурсы, уроки фотошопа, adobe photoshop, видеоуроки фотошопа, заработок на дому, заработок в интернете, купить, купить диски, магазины интернет продуктов, бизнес старт, форекс, как создать сайт" name="Keywords"/>
            <title>Лучшие инфопродукты для домашнего бизнеса</title>
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="header">
                <img alt="Логотип с изображением" src="file://localhost/D:/Создание%20сайты%20 (блога)%20визитки/infoproduct.pusku.com/img/screen.jpg"></div>
                <div class="top-menu"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Сохранил его с расширением html. Создал второй текстовой документ, в нем написал это

```
.top-menu {
    display: block;
    width: 1250px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    background: url ('.../776e4c4406fb9dcd6041bafc2a45a17c.png');
    background: url ('.../26b90e57bf6a4a9f18931a78cf20f0bb.png');
    background-repeat: no repeat;
}

.top-menu:hover {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
}

.top-menu:active {
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

Сохранил с расширением css.

Мне нужно, чтобы когда я наводил на левую надпись, левая выделялась и нажималась, когда наводил на правую, правая выделялась и нажималась. Подскажите, где ошибка?

Comment: @sutuliy_9_0, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Не нужно ставить пробел перед active и hover.

Answer (score 1):

Не могу точно определить, в чем проблема.

Но вот две ошибки:

1. background: url ('.../776e4c4406fb9dcd6041bafc2a45a17c.png');
   Эту строчку браузер проигнорирует, так как следующая (background) заменит все стили для фона
2. В теле документа после изображения идет закрывающий тэг (/div). Возможно, вы по невнимательности не там его поставили. Или же хотели закрыть тэг img, который закрывать не надо (он как <br>)